# Belkin F1DC116H Console

Tags: drivers

Trying to utilize a Belkin F1DC116H Console on an Ubuntu machine, no keyboard or mouse, works on my windows 8 machine.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The screen works?

Comment: The screen works

Comment: I'm not familiar with this kind of equipment, can you say me how it's connected to the rack (I figured out that it's a server with ubuntu installed)? Can you post the output of `lsusb` on the rack when the terminal is connected?

Comment: It's a rack mount computer calculating peripheral geometry measurements, connected to the KVM console by Belkin Dual-Port USB Micro-Cable

Comment: What about `lsusb`? Can you get it via `ssh`?

Comment: I've no power currently, I'll respond back when power is reconnected

Comment: Ok. Why there isn't power?